# How to I deal with root expression without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my current course on mathmatics I'm getting several (automatically generated) tasks to solve in the following form:

Which is the smallest integer that is larger than $\sqrt{7+\sqrt{5}}$

This can of course be converted to: $(7+5^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but I can't really see how that's helping.

Is there an easy way of converting root expressoins such as the one above to readable values without using a calculator?

This is basically Algebra 101 so it shouldn't really be anything complicated......

Comment: **Hint:** Square that number to get an idea of how large the resulting number is, then take the square root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd answer this by asking what is the smallest perfect square that is larger than $7 + \sqrt{5}$, since $$\sqrt{7+\sqrt{5}} < n \iff 7 + \sqrt{5} < n^2 \text{ for positive } n$$

Since $9<7 + \sqrt{5}<10$, $16$ is the smallest perfect square greater than it, thus the answer is 4.

Note that you could apply the trick of looking at perfect squares to estimate this sort of root expression as well.

Answer (score 3):

One approach you can take is to start with some obvious inequality from which you can "build" the more complex expression that you want to make a statement about. In this case, consider the fact that $9>\sqrt{5}>2$.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
& 9>\sqrt{5}>2 \\
\implies &16>7+\sqrt{5}>9 \\
\implies &4>\sqrt{7+\sqrt{5}}>3.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the answer is $4$.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would solve a problem like this is I would estimate. So in this case $\sqrt{5}$ is a bit more than $2$. So lets fill in $2$, we now only have the square root of $9$ left, which is obviously $3$. But since $\sqrt{5}$ was a bit more than the number we filled in we know it has to be bigger than $3$, therefore the smallest integer larger than $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{5}}$ is $4$.

I think Scene's answer is better, even though his conclusion should be 4 instead of 3, as $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{5}} > 3$, therefore the smallest integer bigger than that has to be 4.